# Creating break lines before desired line length keeping chunk prefix

Tags: shell, regular-expression, perl

I want to break lines of code (adding `#'`) when they make part of chunk (line begins with `#'` (`#\x27`)), when exceeding 100 cols.

My solution does not work for several chunks:

Example file:

```
#' chunk line
#' big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split
#' ruler90123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
#'
not chunk line do nothing

big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line

#' chunk line
#' big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split
#' ruler90123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
#'
not chunk line do nothing

big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line
```

My try: (works if only one chunk present)

```
perl -0777 -pe '
  s{#\x27.*#\x27}{                          q{ gets lines from #\x27 to #\x27 (chunk) };
    ($r = $&) =~ s/\n!\n#\x27//g;           q{ removes breaks except followed by #\x27 }; 
    $r =~ s/\G.{0,100}(\s|.$)\K/\n#\x27 /g; q{ before column 100 adds break + #\x27 };
    $r =~ s/#\x27 #\x27/#\x27/g;            q{ removes duplicated #\x27 };
    $r =~ s/\n\n/\n/g;                      q{ removes duplicated breaks };
    $r
  }gse' < chunks.txt
```

Expected output: (two times this)

```
#' chunk line
#' big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split big chunk line to split
#' big chunk line to split
#' ruler90123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
#'
not chunk line do nothing

big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line big do nothing line
```

## Workaround in R

```
psum <- function(...,na.rm=FALSE) {
  rowSums(do.call(cbind,list(...)),na.rm=na.rm)
}    

gblines<-readLines("chunks.txt")

newgblines<-character()
i<-1
j<-1
repeat {
  newgblines[j] <- gblines[i]
    if (grepl("^#\'",newgblines[j] ) & nchar( newgblines[j] ) > 100 ) { # select lines with more than 100 and beginning in #'
      repeat{
        greps<-gregexpr(pattern ="\\s",newgblines[j])[[1]] # get position of spaces
        lenG<-length(greps)
        sums<-psum(-greps , rep(100,lenG ) )               # calculate which space is closest to col. 100
        index <- which(sums>0)
        minSums<- min(sums[index])
        index2<-which(sums==minSums)                       # index of space in greps
        cutpoint<-greps[index2]
        nchar2<-nchar(newgblines[j])                       # number of chars. in line
        strFirst <-substr(newgblines[j],1,cutpoint)        # cut before col. 100
        strSecond<-substr(newgblines[j],cutpoint+1,nchar2) # segmente after col. 100
        newgblines[j]<-strFirst
        j<-j+1
        newgblines[j]<-paste0("#\' ",strSecond)
        if (nchar(strSecond)<=100 ){
          break
        }
      } # 
    } #  if
  i <- i+1
  j <- j+1
  if (i>length(gblines) ){
    break
  }
}
newgblines
```

Comment: You've proposed a solution in R but you've tagged with perl. Do I understand you want a perl solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative universal answer that avoids using chunks ending in #'
It is not perfect but works better

```
perl -0777 -pe '
q{ 4 manual entries };
  $max_length = 100;
  $line_filter_pattern = "#\x27 ";                  
  $prefix_pattern = "#\x27 ";         
  $break_point = " ";                               q{ character in which to break lines };
  
  $linebreak_prefix = "\n$prefix_pattern";          q{ \n is linebreak };
  $lp_length = length($linebreak_prefix);

q{act in lines with prefix pattern };

  s{$line_filter_pattern.*?$}{
    ($r2 = $r = $&);

q{    check if splitting makes changes };
      $r2 =~ s/\G.{0,$max_length}($break_point|.$)\K/$linebreak_prefix/gs;
      if(length($r2) > length($r) + $lp_length) {

q{      add breaks and prefixes in a loop way };
        $r = $r2;
        $r =~ s/$linebreak_prefix$//g;
      }
  $r }gsem' < input.file > output.file
```

Answer (score 3):

You were almost there.

Do these two changes:

- change

  ```
  s{#\x27.*#\x27}{
  ```

  to

  ```
  s{#\x27.*?#\x27$}{
  ```
- and change

  ```
  }gse' < fileName
  ```

  to

  ```
  }mesg' < fileName
  ```

Basically you were doing a greedy search-n-eplace. Whereas what you need is a block oriented search-n-replace operation.

Using the `#'`  marker which sees a newline to its right is the block end and the `.*?` regex is the non-greedy version of `.*`

More details in [perl docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)